# SQL Count doesn't count number of rows of data in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, count

I created below sub to count no of data occurrence in a SQL Server table where specific value occur in the same table. But, it does not count as I require. The sub tries to count no of users for particular clinic names in the table. But, it counts 0 only.

```
    Private Sub chUser()

    conn = New SqlConnection(conStr)
    conn.Open()
    myConn.clName = clNameDGV.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value
    MsgBox(myConn.clName)
    Dim comStr As String = "Select Count(*) as clName from Login_Detail Where Clinic_Name = '" & myConn.clName & "'"
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand(comStr, conn)
    Dim i As Integer = comm.ExecuteScalar()

    If i = 0 Then
        If MessageBox.Show("No User Information found for '" + clNameDGV.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value + "'." + vbNewLine + "Do you want to enter new user details ?", "No Users Found", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = vbYes Then
            Dim nf As New CreateUser
            nf.TopMost = True
            nf.ShowDialog(Me)
        End If
    Else
        Dim nf1 As New LoginForm
        nf1.TopMost = True
        nf1.ShowDialog(Me)

    End If
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Where's the error happening, what isn't working. I see a few things here...

Comment: The sql command does not count the no of data occurence

Comment: I seen that. Did you set breakpoints in your code and step through?

Comment: I did set the break points on executescalar and it shows the result 0

Comment: Try that and step through checking what is going on....

Comment: try `Dim i As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar())` Also, have you printed `comStr`? maybe `& Trim( myConn.clName) & `

Comment: try `LIKE` in where cluase i.e `Select Count(*) as clName from Login_Detail Where Clinic_Name like  '%" & myConn.clName & "%'`

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
Private Sub chUser()
    conn = New SqlConnection(conStr)
    conn.Open()
    myConn.clName = clNameDGV.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value
    MsgBox(myConn.clName)
    Dim comStr As String = "Select Count(*) as clName from Login_Detail Where Clinic_Name = N'" & myConn.clName & "'"
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand(comStr,conn)
    //Dim i As Integer = comm.ExecuteScalar()
    Dim dt As DataTable  
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(comm)
    da.Fill(dt)
    Dim i As Integer = Integer.parse(dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString())
    If i = 0 Then
        If MessageBox.Show("No User Information found for '" + clNameDGV.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value + "'." + vbNewLine + "Do you want to enter new user details ?", "No Users Found", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = vbYes Then
            Dim nf As New CreateUser
            nf.TopMost = True
            nf.ShowDialog(Me)
        End If
    Else
        Dim nf1 As New LoginForm
        nf1.TopMost = True
        nf1.ShowDialog(Me)

    End If
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```